# Finding Marginal Density function of a joint density function

Tags: probability, integration

$$f(y_1,y2) = (1/2)y_1 + (1/4)y_2,\\ 0 \le y_1 \le 1, \\0 \le y_2 \le 2
\\ 0\text{ elsewhere.} $$

How would I find the marginal density function for $Y_1$, and $Y_2$?

To find $Y_1$ you would do $f_1(y1) = \int_0^1 f(y_1,y_2)dy_2$ and for $Y_2$ you do $f1(y1) = \int_0^2 f(y_1,y_2)dy_1$.

For some strange reason when I do it out, it does not match the solutions that I have. I believe I might be doing the integration wrong. Could someone walk through it so I could see the process that you do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned,$$f_1(y_1)=
\int_0^2 f(y_1,y_2) dy_2= \int_0^2 \frac 12 y_1dy_2
 + \frac 14 \int_0^2 y_2 dy_2
= y_1 +  \frac 12
\\
f_2(y_2) = \int_0^1  f(y_1,y_2) dy_1
=\frac 12 \int_0^1 y_1dy_1 + \frac 14y_2 
= \frac 14 + \frac 14y_2 
$$

Comment: is the first integral wrong? Shouldn't it be from 0 to 1? and the second one from 0 to 2? Or is it suppose to be like that?

Comment: when you integrate with respect to $y_1$ it should be on the range $[0,1]$; with $y_2$ on the range $[0,2]$.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much!